# iPad app fails to install in new device added to Ad Hoc provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, ota

I am using an enterprise account for deploying an internal iPad app. The app is signed with an adhoc provisioning profile, so far I never used the entitlements file. The app is deployed in a web server and installed via OTA.

The customer has some 80 devices added in the provisioning portal. The app is installing fine in every device except for one recently added and the only difference I can see is that all the devices have iOS Team Provisioning Profile installed (not sure why because AFAIK they are not development devices).

When the customer tried to install the app in the latest added device (which was included in the adhoc profile and the app built again), it downloads but fails to install. However, he downloaded the ipa file and could install it using the cable.

I also tried with one of my development iPads which is also present on the customer's adhoc profile. I deleted all the profiles, then install the app via OTA. The app installs and runs fine, however when I go to check the installed profiles on the devices (under settings/general) there is not a single profile installed.

My questions are as follows:

- Is the entitlements file a requirement?
- If it's required, why the app is working fine with the rest of devices (could be due to the team
  profile?)?
- Why isn't the profile installed when I install the app on my development device? The profile was installed on the rest of devices when installing the app.

I just cannot understand why this is workig with with the other devices but failing with this one.

Comment: will you download and add profile to xcode after adding the device?

Comment: Have you added the UDID of new device in the provisioning profile?

Comment: @HChouhan02 yes, I downloaded and replaced new profile in xCode after adding the new device.

Comment: @Rupesh yes, I added the new device to the profile using the provisioning portal

Comment: Delete the entitlements.plist and add new one, Build the app and carefully check  the build results shown at the last.

Comment: @Rupesh As you can see in my question I am not using any entitlements file, that's why I asked if that is a must (I think it is so I don't understand why it's working with the rest of the 80 devices)

Comment: ok then what was the error comes when you are going to install the app on that device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a stupid problem.

After adding the new device to the profile, downloading, importing it to xCode and rebuilding the app, the profile embeded inside the ipa file still was the old one. I just cleaned the project and everything was fine (probably xCode didn't update because it was the same edited profile)